# is there a reason to use ++$i in for loop?

Tags: php, loops, post-increment, pre-increment

i have following code for loop

```
for ($i=0; $i<=(count($subusers)-1); ++$i) {
```

is there a reason to use ++$i instead of $i++ if latter doing same thing?

Comment: ok, so it just stylistic meaning, its all i want to hear, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

++$i is a micro-optimisation, it executes fractionally faster than $i++. However, unless the $subusers array is being changed within the loop so that count($subusers) can change from one iteration to the next, then any slight positive gain in speed is being negated (and then some) by counting the number of array entries every iteration.

Note that $i++ and ++$i would both execute at the end of each iteration of the loop. It isn't the same as initialising $i to 1 rather than to 0.

Comment: @llamerr: Be very careful with stuff like this - it's touted as a micro-optimization, but I wouldn't be surprised if PHP optimized out the difference anyway. Just focus on writing clean code.

Comment: thanks for warning, i just trying to undertand someone else code on current project

Answer (score 6):

In a for loop, it doesn't matter since you're not doing anything with the returned value.

However you should still note the difference between `++$i` and `$i++`, which is that `$i++` returns `$i` and `++$i` returns `$i+1`.

For example...

```
$i=0;
echo $i++; //0
echo ++$i; //2
```

Comment: yeah i understand it, but i dont understand why someone use it in for loop, if result is the same as for $i++ - it executes after a cycle and before next cycle.

Comment: In the for loop would this not be to incur the incrementation of $i but keeping it as its existing value during the loop?

Comment: @Blue: No. The third section of the for loop is executed **for effect only**. That is, it is executed but the return value is not used for anything. So for example, `for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){...}` is the same as `for($i=0;$i<5;5000000+ ++$i){...}`

Answer (score 2):

In this case there is no difference because you are in a loop.

I would suggest you read up a bit on post and pre incrementation since it is always one of the favorite questions in interviews ^^

if you do i++, the value of i is first used then incremented

if you do ++i, i is incremented then used

for example 
int i = 0;
while (aBool){
   print (i++);
}
will show 0,1,2,3,4,...

as

int i = 0;
while (aBool){
   print (++i);
}
will show 1,2,3,4,5,...

Answer (score 1):

No, in this case it is only stylistic. Maybe someone just wanted to use a pre-increment operator for once.

Comment: well I guess its really a programming habit ^^, as most people I prefer i++, but I know some people that prefer ++i. Like people that like to init variable at -1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

++$i make php execution fast and also increment the thing on the same line of code.

this link may helpful:- http://ilia.ws/archives/12-PHP-Optimization-Tricks.html

Comment: It does not make php execution fast.

Comment: If you put that link in your answer I'll undownvote you. I still don't agree with your attitude about ++$i vs $i++ as I feel it's really not important - but the link does back your answer enough that it's no longer worth the downvote :)